# How to get the chips inside the input box?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have added this input box in ReactJS that created chips, but I am unable to get the chips inside the input box.

[image]

If I keep on adding more chips, the input box just keeps going down.

I want to keep my input box position and size fixed, and these chips inside the box. What approach should I use?

Below is my React jsx code:

```
<div className="chips" onClick={this.focusInput}>
    {chips}
    <input
        type="text"
        className="form-input chips-input"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
        onKeyUp={this.clearInvalidChars}
    />
</div>
```

Edit: I tried the first solution like this:

```
<div className="form-input chips" onClick={this.focusInput}>
    {chips}
    <input
        type="text"
        className="chips-input"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
        onKeyUp={this.clearInvalidChars}
    />
</div>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I am quite noob in CSS, can anyone tell me what can I do so that the items do not pop out of the box.

Comment: can we have some running code snippet, so that we can trigger the specifc your problem.

Comment: This is just a CSS problem if we see it in a generic way, but in your case may be some specific issue, so that whould be helpful if we have running code snippet

Answer (score 3):

for things like this, I usually hide the input, and make a label around the whole thing `for` the input's id, and style that to look like the actual input.

```
<label for="chips-input" class="chips">
  <span>Chip x</span>
  <span>Chip x</span>
  <span>Chip x</span>
  <span>Chip x</span>
  <input type="text" id="chips-input">
</label>

.chips{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  input{
    border: none;
    appearance: none;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/LYpzyde

If only there was a way you could find one of these online... ;P

[image: Stack overflow tags]
[image: Stack overflow inspect element]

Answer (score 3):

I just had to roughly do this for you. Next time you must provide Snippet for other respectful developers to work with.

The idea here is not to put your chips inside your input. input is not a container so putting elements inside of it isn't ideal. Create a wrapper `<div>` or any container that can container your chips and your input. and then style it like an input, usually putting a border would do.

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".chip-input");
var chips = document.querySelector(".chips");

document.querySelector(".form-field")
   .addEventListener('click',() => {
      input.style.display = 'block';
      input.focus();
   });
   
input.addEventListener('blur',()=>{
  input.style.display = 'none';
});

input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
   if(event.which === 13)
   {
     
      

      chips.appendChild(function ()
      {
         var _chip = document.createElement('div');

         _chip.classList.add('chip');
         _chip.addEventListener('click', chipClickHandler);

         _chip.append(
            (function ()
            {
               var _chip_text = document.createElement('span');
               _chip_text.classList.add('chip--text');
               _chip_text.innerHTML = input.value;

               return _chip_text;
            })(),
            (function ()
            {
               var _chip_button = document.createElement('span');
               _chip_button.classList.add('chip--button');
               _chip_button.innerHTML = 'x';

               return _chip_button;
            })()
         );

         return _chip;
      }());
      input.value = '';
   }
});
  
function chipClickHandler(event){
   chips.removeChild(event.currentTarget);
}
```

```css
.form-field{
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 34px;
  border: 2px solid #737679;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  cursor: text;
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(25,25,25,0.2);
}

.form-field .chips .chip {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  
  background-color: #0077b5;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.form-field .chips .chip{
  float: left;
}

.form-field .chips .chip .chip--button {
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #004471;
  display: inline-block;
}
.form-field .chips .chip .chip--text {
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: no;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none
}

.form-field > input{
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="chips">
  </div>
  <input placeholder="Enter something here" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="chip-input" />
</div>
<p><strong>Just type in your text and press enter. BingooO! It works.</strong></p>
```